# Bug casting String, Integer, Double using HashMap

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I have some strange bug on Android 2.3 and lower.

I have following code:

```
HashMap<Somekey, Object> data = new HashMap<Somekey, Object>();
data.put(somekey, "asdfdsafdsf");
String value = (String) data.get(somekey);
```

on the last line I have ClassCastException: **get(somekey)** returns **Boolean** value instead of **String**. This error appears not only with String type, with Integer and Double too.

I don't understand why, because this code correctly works on android 4.0.3 and higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well even if your code was running (???) your code is wrong and you should fix it. Maybe by checking the type with instanceof before casting.

You could do it the dirty way also:

```
String value = data.get(somekey).toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

So you did not put *any* boolean/Boolean into the map? Because `Somekey` might have a wrong `hashCode()` implementation, maybe all the same code, and the earlier HashMap implementations might have been buggy.

Purely the above code, without any Boolean, could not deliver that error.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code and it works :

```
Somekey somekey = new Somekey();
HashMap<Somekey, Object> data = new HashMap<Somekey, Object>();
data.put(somekey, "asdfdsafdsf");
String value = (String) data.get(somekey);
```

May be you are not creating a `java.util.HashMap` but a custom and buggy implementation, for example :

```
public class HashMap<K, V> extends java.util.HashMap<K, V> {
    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        return (V)(Object)true;
    }
}
```